# Conditional JUnit 4 test execution based on Spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-profiles

I have an application that uses `"spring.profiles.active"` to decide which profile to work upon. We are using JUnit 4. I need to condition my test classes based on the Profile in use. So if `"spring.profiles.active" = "X"` I need to execute tests in Class A and if `"spring.profiles.active" = "Y"` I need to execute tests in Class B.

I have tried using

```
@IfProfileValue(name="spring.profiles.active", value="X")
```

but the class with the above annotation is never executed.

```
System.Properties()
System.getProperties(){java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=<<Masked>>, java.vm.version=25.191-b12, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=;, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=US, user.script=, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=<<Masked>>, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_191-b12, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, , os.arch=amd64, spring.profiles.active=X
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you added @IfProfileValue(name="spring.profiles.active", value="X") in class level.. 
Try adding for test methods in class and check.

Comment: I tried it both at Class level as well as method level

 //@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:<<Masked>>" })
 //@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 //@PrepareForTest(<<Masked>>.class)
        @IfProfileValue(name="spring.profiles.active", value="X")
 public class <<Masked>> ...